# How to configure eclipse IDE for Selenium WebDriver to work on multiple platforms?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, jar, ide

I am working on Eclipse IDE to run Selenium both on MAC and PC (Windows/Linux). I am just trying to figure out if there is a way to add external jar files to the project in Windows and use them in the MAC without re-adding them in the MAC. I use GitHub to sync the files between both machines which also syncs the address to the jar files in my windows machine, but I cannot use them in the MAC even though they are in the same folder in both machines. I found that I can use an if statement to configure the ChromeDriver files between both machines but I couldn't find a way to do the same with the jar files. Does anyone have some insight?

Comment: You can create Maven project and use Maven to manage selenium and other jar files cross platform.

Comment: I just discovered that. But there is another issue! I just entered the selenium dependency in the POM file with version 3.11 and updated the Junit to 4.12. The new problem is that when i enter WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); The ChromeDriver(); is not recognized

Answer (score 0):

Please try add below dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

After eclipse download all dependentcies, expand the `Maven Dependencies` in eclipse and check there is `selenium-chrome-driver-3.11.0.jar`.

[image]

Comment: that is exactly what I have. I go that from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.11.0

Comment: but i still have the same problem

Comment: I just fixed the problem!I think one of the jar files were corrupted. if I changed the version to 3.10.0 it worked, but not on 3.11.0. So, I closed eclipse and then located the .m folder and deleted it, and then restarted eclipse and maven was able to rebuild the selenium jar files with the version 3.11.0.